# Load Plist in UITableView for only 10 row

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, plist

Actually this is to follow up my question before
[UITableView show only first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546978/uitableview-show-only-first-row).

Now my problem is that I only want to view the 10 list in my plist. If there are 11 items, the first item will be replace by the second and so on so my list only 10 items.

And this is my code to save to the plist:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];


if (nil == array) {
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}


NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[list addObject:resi.text];

[array addObject:list];

[array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];
```

And this is the whole code for my table view that have been modified

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSArray *list = (NSArray *)[self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(list && [list count] > 0) { //to check and avoid any crash
        cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // get paths from root direcory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

    array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    [myHistoryTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing and needs more detail. I think you are saying that you want your table to only display the ***last*** 10 items in a plist of any length, yes?  What generated this plist anyways?  Is it simply a `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` that you wrote to a file?

Comment: Hi Michael,yes I want my table to display only last 10 items and its actualy array from UITextField, this is the code         NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [list addObject:resi.text];

[array addObject:list];

[array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([array count] > 10) {
    array = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([array count] - 10, 10)];
}
```

if you don't want to overwrite the original array create a second one which serves as the dataSource of the tableView:

```
array = /* load from plist */;
if ([array count] > 10) {
    self.dataSourceArray = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([array count] - 10, 10)];
}
else {
    self.dataSourceArray = array;
}
```